# How to do such a layout in xml? Android

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I want a Layout that is as big as the screen with two rows  and three columns

like that image => 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2024237/Bildschirmfoto-DroidDraw.png

the colors should be buttons...

please help .... i cant figure it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using LinearLayouts and setting the children to fill_parent on both width and height and assigning them the same layout_weight you would get the desired effect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <Button 
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
        <Button 
            android:text="Button 2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
        <Button 
            android:text="Button 3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <Button 
            android:text="Button 4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
        <Button 
            android:text="Button 5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
        <Button 
            android:text="Button 6"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```